# python doctest is not running test when I'm running command from command line

Tags: python, python-3.x, string, list, doctest

I'm having the following code inside a file `./src/string.py`

```
#!/usr/bin/env python3.7


def extract_upper(phrase):
    """
    Take sthe string and returns the only uppercase letters

    The following is a doctest
    >>> extract_upper("Hello There, BOB")
    ['H', 'T', 'B', 'O', '']
    """

    return list(filter(str.isupper, phrase))


def extract_lower(phrase):
    return list(filter(str.islower, phrase))

if __name__=='__main__':
    print(f'Hello from string')

print(f"__name__ in string.py {__name__}")
```

When I'm running below command from cmdline.

```
python3.7 -m doctest -v  src/helpers/string.py
```

This doesn't run any test. I'm getting the below output.

```
19 items had no tests:
    string
    string.Formatter
    string.Formatter._vformat
    string.Formatter.check_unused_args
    string.Formatter.convert_field
    string.Formatter.format
    string.Formatter.format_field
    string.Formatter.get_field
    string.Formatter.get_value
    string.Formatter.parse
    string.Formatter.vformat
    string.Template
    string.Template.__init__
    string.Template._invalid
    string.Template.safe_substitute
    string.Template.substitute
    string._TemplateMetaclass
    string._TemplateMetaclass.__init__
    string.capwords
0 tests in 19 items.
0 passed and 0 failed.
Test passed.
```

Can someone help me out with what I'm doing wrong or what am I missing.

Comment: the code in `./src/string.py` but you run it for `src/helpers/string.py`. is it mistake?

Comment: Actually that was a typo, the code is in `src/helpers/string.py`.

Comment: I figured out the issue `python3.7 -m doctest -v  src/helpers/string.py`, this was somehow triggered the test on the default python string module, and there is no doctest written there, so it was not running any tests. After renaming string.py to strings.py, running `python3.7 -m doctest -v  ./src/helpers/strings.py` gives expected output.